# C# - is there any difference between x.ToString("D") and x.ToString(), where x is type int?

Tags: c#, tostring

My personal preference is `x.ToString()`, since it has slightly fewer letters. Is there any advantage to either one?

Comment: Officially, the no-argument version is the same as using a format string of `"G"`, not `"D"`.

Answer (score 9):

The main point of `.ToString("D")` is that it allows you to specify the preceding number of digits.

e.g,

```
var i = 123;

var stringed = i.ToString("D5");//stringed = 00123
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at what the "D" actually means here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

> "D" or "d"    Decimal Result: Integer digits with optional negative sign.
>
> Supported by: Integral types only.
>
> Precision specifier: Minimum number of digits.
>
> Default precision specifier: Minimum number of digits required.
>
> More information: The Decimal("D") Format Specifier.
>
> 1234 ("D") -> 1234
>
> -1234 ("D6") -> -001234

So, depending on the format of the output you're looking for, that's what the different format (or precision) specifiers can help dictate your output.

Answer (score 2):

From the Microsoft documentation:

> To format an Int32 value as an integral string with no leading zeros, you can call the parameterless ToString() method. By using the "D" format specifier, you can also include a specified number of leading zeros in the string representation.

It would appear that `"D"` without digits is what `Int32.ToString()` uses by default.

There is then, no difference in output between the two.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#DFormatString)

> The "D" (or decimal) format specifier converts a number to a string of
>   decimal digits (0-9), prefixed by a minus sign if the number is
>   negative. This format is supported only for integral types.

It shows the same result for the case `"D"`.

But it will pad with zeros to the left of your `int` if you `"Dx"` (x is a number)

`ToString()` is enough for you to convert to `string`

Comment: It does not give the same result.

Comment: @Woj In what case does it not give the same result?